# Understanding the $\mathcal{L}^0(\mu)$ space

Tags: measure-theory, lp-spaces

After having introduced the $\mathcal{L}^p(\mu)$ spaces for $p\in(0,\infty)$, my book has a little remark that we can expand the definition to $p=0$.

Let $(X,\mathcal{E},\mu)$ be a measure space.

Let $\mathcal{M}(\mathcal{E})=\{f:X\to \mathbb{R}\ |\ f \text{ is } \mathcal{E}-\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})\text{-measurable}\}$ i.e. the set of measurable functions.

For $p=0$ we define the $\mathcal{L}^p(\mu)$ space as:

$$ \mathcal{L}^0(\mu)=\{f\in \mathcal{M}(\mathcal{E})|\ \lim_{t\to\infty}\mu(\{ |f|\geq t\})=0 \}$$

The book then simply state that $\mathcal{L}^0(\mu)$ is a vector-space (left as an exercise to the reader), and by markov's inequality $\mathcal{L}^r(\mu)\subseteq \mathcal{L}^0(\mu)$ for all $r\in (0,\infty)$. That is it.

I am now trying to understand what this space is.

My idea is that this atleast <strike>includes</strike> excludes functions where $f(x) \to \pm \infty$ for $x\to \pm \infty$, since for all $t$ there will be an infinite interval were the function is larger.

We can have a function with vertical asymptotes, but i cant think of a way to make them satisfy $\lim_{t\to\infty}\mu(\{ |f|\geq t\})>0$ without having uncountably many vertical asymptotes, and i do not think that is possible.

Am i heading in the right direction when thinking about $\mathcal{L}^0(\mu)$, or how do we intuitively think about this space?

Comment: be careful because the notation $\mathcal{L}^0(\mu)$ is also used to denote the sets of $\mu$-measurable functions (what is a vector space and contains every other $\mathcal{L}^p(\mu)$ space also)

Comment: Perhaps that is why i could not find the answer on the internet. Is there another name for this space, or is it not something that is widely considered?

Comment: it is the first time that I see the space defined in your question, however Im not mathematician so, who knows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "My idea is that this at least $\color{red}{includes}$ functions where $f(x)\to\pm\infty$ for $x\to\infty$, ..."

I guess that you really meant to exclude them. Mind you that the space $\mathcal{L}^{0}(\mu)$ defined in OP does depend on $\mu$ as well. For example,

1. If $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^d$, then $\mathcal{L}^{0}(\mu)$ exclues any measurable functions $f: \mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $|f(x)| \to \infty$ as $|x| \to \infty$. Of course there are other examples, such as $\tan(\cdot)$ on $\mathbb{R}$.
2. On the other hand, if $\mu$ is a finite measure, then $\mathcal{L}^{0}(\mu) = \mathcal{M}(\mathcal{E})$ by the continuity of $\mu$ from above.

In fact, it follows that

$$ f \notin \mathcal{L}^{0}(\mu) \qquad \Leftrightarrow \qquad \mu(\{|f| \geq t\}) = \infty \quad \text{for all} \quad t. $$

Comment: Yeah, of course i meant it the other way. Are you saying that $tan \not\in \mathcal{L}^0(\mu)$, for that is one of the things i thought about. To me it seemed like a countable number of arbitrary small intervals, and i thought that would be a null set.

Comment: @Nikolaj1000000 Note that $$\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} \Bigl( n\pi+\arctan(t), n\pi+\frac{\pi}{2} \Bigr) \subseteq \{x\in\mathbb{R}:\tan(x)>t\}$$ But since each interval apperaing on the left-hand side has the same positive length, we have $$\operatorname{Leb}(\{x\in\mathbb{R}:\tan(x)>t\}) = +\infty$$ where $\operatorname{Leb}$ is the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$. This shows that $\tan(\cdot) \notin \mathcal{L}^{0}(\operatorname{Leb})$.

Comment: Perhaps you can see were my logic goes wrong. If $\tan\not\in \mathcal{L}^0(\text{Leb})$ then $\lim_{t\to\infty} \text{Leb}(\{|\tan(x)|>t\})>0$. 
 We have (I believe)$\{|\tan(x)|>t\}=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} \Big(\left((n+1)\pi+\arctan(-t),n\pi+\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\cup \left(n\pi+\arctan(t),n\pi+\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\Big)$, but $\left((n+1)\pi+\arctan(-t),n\pi+\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\to \emptyset$ and $\left(n\pi+\arctan(t),n\pi+\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\to \emptyset$ for $t \to \infty$ since $\tan$ is not defined for $\frac{\pi}{2}+n$, so would not $\lim_{t\to\infty}\text{Leb}(\{|\tan(x)|>t\})=0$?

Comment: @Nikolaj1000000, Even if $A_n\supseteq A_{n+1}$ holds for all $n$, the limit $$\lim_{N\to\infty}\mu(A_n) = \mu\Biggl(\bigcap_n A_n\Biggr)$$ holds only when $\mu(A_n) < \infty$ for some $n$. Without such restriction, there are obvious counter-examples such as $A_n=[n,\infty)$ under the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Thanks, i see now. Another comment mentioned that this definition of $\mathcal{L}^{0}(\mu)$ is not a common one. Does this space have another more common name, or is it not usually a space that is studied in measure theory?

Comment: @Nikolaj1000000, To be honest I am not sure. In my area of study, people are predominantly concerned with finite measure spaces, where $\mathcal{L}^{0}(\mu)$ defined in whatever sense equals the family of all measurable functions. But I would prefer to use different notation for such family.